# Видеоредактор.

Tags: видео, редактор

Какой программой лучше пользоваться для достижения наилучших спецэффектов и оформления записанного видео. 
Пожалуйста скиньте название программы и мануал.

Что нибудь такое [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hDlif8Km4S4&feature=related)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше всего Adobe After Effects в этом деле будет. А вот здесь можно посмотреть уроки к этой программе: http://www.videocopilot.net/

Answer (score 1):

Adobe After Effects отлично подходит для этих целей. 
Ролик-пример, который Вы указали был на 90% сделан по туториалам первопроходца в этом деле - Эндрю Крамера (Andrew Kramer), основателя [videocopilot.net](http://videocopilot.net).

Сам туториал - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UWppqLrS6cU